# Square summability of sequences of the form $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n\,dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

For a function  $f\in L^2(0,1)$ let
$$a_n=\int_0^1 f(x)x^n\,dx.$$ Is the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ square summable for any $f$ ?

I have tried to prove or disprove that by testing  specific examples, but with no success. I have impression that the question might be associated with the boundedness of the Hilbert matrix $H=\{(n+m+1^{-1}\}_{n,m=0}^\infty $ on $\ell^2$ space, i.e.
$$\|Ha\|_{\ell^2}\le \pi \|a\|_{\ell^2},\qquad a=\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$$

Comment: I'd expect that the answer is affirmative, since for $f(x)=(1-x)^{-\beta}$ the thresholds for $f(x)$ being square-integrable and $a_n$ being square-summable concide at $\beta=\frac12$.

Comment: I have tried $(1-x)^{-1/2+\delta}.$ The ratio of norms is indeed bounded according to my calculations.

Comment: If $f$ is real and not $0$ then $\sum a_n^2 < \pi \int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx$. See Hardy Littlewood Polya: Inequalities, p. 237

Comment: @Gerd Thanks a lot !